# JQuery load (Ajax) and PHP validation

Tags: php, jquery

Ok, I am having a small issue. I have a page, where it has a DIV in it. When the page loads, it will load another page in the DIV. For this, I used JQuery load function, that is AJAX, the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".div").hide().load("page.php").fadeIn(5000);
});
```

Good, everything is fine, I do not have any issue when the page is loading and appearing to the DIV.

Now, in this page, which appears in the DIV, it has a textarea. The page has PHP validation codes for the textarea. If the textarea is empty, the user gets a message to fill it before sending. Here is the PHP code below:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (isset($_POST['textfirst'])) {

$textarea = strip_tags($_POST['textfirst']);

if (empty($textarea)) {
echo "You have to fill your answer";    
} else {
bla bla bla bla bla......
}
}
}
```

Again here, nothing is wrong, the PHP validation is working perfectly.

The problem comes, when the form is empty and submitted, my page loads the page in the DIV and no error message from the PHP appears. Why? In other words, if the user has not filled the textarea, he/she gets the message to fill it, but when the user submits the form empty, it reloads the page which loads the other page in the DIV again, thus, no error message appears.

Thank!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How should user gets the message?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve? What do you mean? The form should not be empty when sending, else all is OK.. but when the form is empty and submitted, the error message from PHP does not appear as it loads the AJAX page again...

Comment: AJAX doesn't work that way, you should use `$.ajax` function and prevent default action of the submit event.

Comment: hmmm ok i will try to do that..

Comment: I did this: $.ajax({url:"page.php",success:function(result){
    $(".div").html(result);
  }}); still not work as the AJAX page reloads again..

Comment: ah no lol, iframe is not the solution, Mike Brant is right in his answer... it will crystal clear reload the main page again in such situation.. so i think i will remove AJAX completely. As the page is light, it will not be a big issue for loading time on any internet connection.. it will just take 1 second to load,...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the target is for the form that is loaded into the div.  It sounds like you are posting the the original page, which does not have the for. Processing logic.  Tis would in essence do nothing but reload the original page.

The form in the div that is loaded via AJAX will need to point to the page that does the actual form processing.  You can't simply reload the original page a hope that a page loaded via AJAX after the initial page load will be able to process your post.

Comment: Can you give me a way to tackle it? The form action has nothing except '#', but of course, it will still reload the main page which will loads the AJAX page again...

Comment: Well, if you want the submit to be done via AJAX, then you need to prevent the default action on form submit and post the form using AJAX. JQuery gives you easy methods to serialize he form and post via AJAX.

Comment: Here is the form tag <form action="#" method="post">. What is the stuff serialize call in JQuery, I will search it and tackle else I will remove the AJAX completely... I gave the reason in other comment